# Multiple postgresql servers with LDAP authentication?

Tags: database, postgresql, authentication, ldap

I have many PG servers using LDAP authentication.
When I got request for new user, I create user account in every PG server so that [LDAP can be used for authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-ldap.html).

But, I wonder is there better way to manage accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement one LDAP-Server as central authentication provider?

Comment: Yes. I have one LDAP server, but still I had to make user account for authentication. PG documentation also mentioned this. 
```This authentication method operates similarly to password except that it uses LDAP as the password verification method. LDAP is used only to validate the user name/password pairs. Therefore the user must already exist in the database before LDAP can be used for authentication.```